# How to Implement Oracle Transaction for two different Method in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, ado.net

I want to use Oracle Transaction for two different method in C#. But unable to figure out how to use it. Basically code in 3Layer Architecture.

Example :-

in Code behind file on Cancel Butto Click.

```
On_Cancel_Button_Click()
{
Cancel Method() //Cancelling Booked Ticket
If (Some Booked Ticket in Waiting)
Calling Confirm Method() //to confirm waiting list ticket
}
```

Cancel & Confirm both method is defined in Aspx.cs file and both are calling BAL class method then DAL Class Method, In BAL, DAL both are calling different Method (In DAL all ADO.Net Code written).

So how to implement Transaction for this scenario.

Comment: You should probably implement the transaction in your BAL.  That way, you don't even have to think about how it interacts with your code behind.

Comment: In BAL the both method look like this :- cancel_Ticket("taking some prameter) and confirm_Ticket("taking some parameter) both are different method and not wrapped in any event. So here how to implement Transaction. I want some hints from your end.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to handle the transaction in the outer scope.

Eg

```
void CancelAndConfirmTicket()
{
  using (var con = new OracleConnection(...))
  {
     con.Open();
     using (var tran = con.BeginTransaction())
     {
        Cancel(con);
        Confirm(con);

        tran.Commit();
     }
  }
```

There are other patterns for sharing a connection between methods (like Dependency Injection), or sharing a transaction (like TransactionScope), but the the idea is the same.  You define the scope and logic of the transaction in an outer layer of the application, and "enlist" the inner layers in the transaction.

Comment: No, I would do it in a single business logic method, but the the idea is the same.

Comment: +1 for the technique, but if you demonstrate it in code-behind, that's exactly where the OP will put it.

Comment: I will try this method, so baiscally i have to pass connection. I defined connection in DAL layer, so should i remove connection details from DAL and pass it to Code Behind.?